# How i can localize days and month name in ChartJS 3.x?

Tags: chart.js

How i can localize days and month names in ChartJS 3.x if scale is set to time?

I read some post which talk about :
option.locale : "it-IT" or option.locale : "en-EN"
i try that option but without success.

Any Idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Moment.js` adapter](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-moment) together with the `moment-with-locales.js` library. The desired `locale` can then be defined through the following statement.

```
moment.locale('it');
```

Please take a look at below runnable sample and see hot it works.

```js
moment.locale('it');

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['2021-02', '2021-03', '2021-06', '2021-07', '2021-08', '2021-10', '2021-11'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Valori',
        data: [75, 56, 44, 54, 22, 38, 48],        
        borderColor: '#D00',
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'month',
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MMMM'
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'MMMM'
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks,
i'm not already able to solve my situation, i think i wrong something, i'm a bit confuse about chart.js documentation, i read chartjs 3.x has moment already included in bundle version. 
So i actually have this JS to  translate charts date, but it dont works:

Chart.js v3.5.1
moment-with-locales.min.js
chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js

I added them in page in the order you can see, i also added moment.locale('it'); before chart declaration but i continue get english months names, and no error in console.

Comment: @Lorenzo: Include `moment-with-locales.min.js` together with `chart.min.js`. `chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js` has nothing to do with `moment.js` but it's a different adapter.